# Annulus Question..

Tags: calculus

Why is that $x^2$ is less than $x$. I find that part confusing. This is because if you put any value greater than $1$, the $x^2$ function will be greater than $x$?!

[image: VOLUME OF SOLIDS]

Comment: $x^2<x$ is true if $0<x<1$

Comment: $0.5^2 < 0.5$.....

Comment: J.W. Tanner is it because 0 and 1 are the limits of integration?

Comment: $(1/2)^2 = 1/4$.  Believe it or not (the general public may not) $1/4 < 1/2$.

Comment: Try sketching the graphs of $y = x$ and $y = x^2$ in the interval $[0, 1]$.  The area between the two curves is the region that is rotated around the $x$-axis.  Notice that if $0 < x < 1$, $x^2 < x$.

Comment: the bounded region is where $x$ is between $0$ and $1$ (so $0$ and $1$ are the limits of integration), and in that interval $x^2<x$

Answer (score 1):

The solution says that $y_2 = x^2 \leq y_1 = x$ on $[0,1].$ You can intuitively understand this by imagining multiplying a small number less than $1$ by itself. You will get a number smaller than the original number. Alternatively, we have that on $[0,1], 0\leq x \leq 1$ and $-1\leq x-1 \leq 0\Rightarrow x(x-1)\leq 0\Rightarrow x^2 \leq x$ (since $(x-1)$ is negative or zero, the inequality is swapped).